# JSTL: html snippet depending on property being null or not. (with not empty)

Tags: jstl

```
<c:forEach items="${list }" var="element">
            <c:if test='${not empty element.radioelement}'>
                <input type="radio" name="${element.name }" id="${element.id }" >
                <label for="${element.id }"></label>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test='${not empty element.divelement}'>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test='${not empty element.breakelement}'>
                <br />
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
```

This is the jstl code I'm trying to find out if it works.
The list is filled with the objects of the class "tyle" which I made myself. These contain the following properties:

```
private String radioelement, divelement, breakelement, name, id;
```

I made sure they all have setters and getters.

I'm trying to make it work so that depending on which property isn't null, that piece of html will be written. (a radiobutton incase the string radioelement isn't null and so forth untill the list ends)

I'm wondering if this will work this way cus if it does I'll probably have a logical fault in my code. As it is now it only registers the breaks and makes any divelement also into a radio.

Comment: That looks right to me, are you saying it doesn't work?

Comment: Well right now the objects where the property divelement isn't null get written as radiobuttons for some reason. I just wanted to make sure if I didn't make a mistake jstl syntax wise.

Comment: When the property divelement contains a string I want a div to be printed, and when the property radioelement contains a string I need a radiobutton to be printed. Right now a radiobutton is made in both cases. However this might be due to something else. I'm rechecking everything.

Comment: Sorry, I take back my comment, but the logic above is right.  It must be the data you're passing in.